# JS duplicates list and json checks out

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'm creating a google maps layout with infoboxes and name list, but somewhere in the code I'm duplicating the list.    I've checked the json to make sure it is valid and it checks out on jslint.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var arrMarkers = [];
    var arrInfoWindows = [];

    function initMap(){
        var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(48.058249, -122.288615);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: centerCoord,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        jQuery.getJSON("/wp-content/themes/the-language-of-puget-sound/js/map12.json", {}, function(data){
            jQuery.each(data.places, function(i, item){
            jQuery("#markers").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + item.English_Name + '</a></li>');
            var image = '/wp-content/themes/the-language-of-puget-sound/js/Marker5-50.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Y_DD, item.X_DD),
                 map: map,
                 icon: image,
                 title: item.English_Name
                 });
                 arrMarkers[i] = marker;
                 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 
        });
        arrInfoWindows[i] = infowindow;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var i = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        // this next line closes all open infowindows before opening the selected one
        for(x=0; x < arrInfoWindows.length; x++){ arrInfoWindows[x].close(); }  
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
           });
       });
    }
    jQuery(function(){
    // initialize map (create markers, infowindows and list)
    initMap();

    // "live" bind click event
    jQuery("#markers a").on("click", function(){
         var i = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    // this next line closes all open infowindows before opening the selected one
    for(x=0; x < arrInfoWindows.length; x++){ arrInfoWindows[x].close(); 
}
arrInfoWindows[i].open(map, arrMarkers[i]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the WP page code with the divs and css.

```
<div class="responsive-map">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
<div id="names">
<strong>Place Names</strong>
<ul id="markers"></ul>
</div>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.responsive-map {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:95.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
}

#names.img { border: 0; }

#map {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    border: 3px solid #93193e;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#names {
    top: 10px;
    left: 800px;
    margin: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Any suggestions of where the list is being duplicated?

Below is a link to the working site.

[http://50.87.248.66/~tulalipl/places/ ]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including sample/test JSON and CSS to go with the HTML/javascript.

Comment: Please provide the [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to the broken site.

Comment: All the code is there, the json has been verified three times and an example of what's happening.    Give me a specific example of what is needed.